# What is Hibernate TransactionStatus.canRollback used for?

Tags: java, hibernate

What is Hibernate `TransactionStatus::canRollback` used for?

Even if `canRollback` returns false, the user can still attempt to rollback.
(The attempt will fail, but nothing bad will happen.)

So why bother to check before rolling back?

I read the [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/resource/transaction/spi/TransactionStatus.html#canRollback--), but wasn't able to use it to answer this question.
In the [source code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/18e6f61041b37698cc04b6a2e244ef51f8f734d6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/transaction/internal/TransactionImpl.java#L124), I see that JPA compliance dictates throwing an `IllegalStateException` if `Transaction::rollback` is called on a non-active transaction. Is that the only reason?

Comment: Introspection, for example logging. The fact that you can do something does not mean you have to. ;)